# Select code in EJS based on form value without refreshing the page in Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, ejs

I have this drop-down in ejs where I need to show a default image, and a custom image when something is submitted in the form. But I want to do this without refreshing the page.

**Important: The submit button is not necessary for me, so change of image by just clicking in drop-down will also be a solution for me.**

`index2.ejs`

```
    <form action="/users/details" method="POST">
      <fieldset>
      <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info" name="selectpicker">
        <optgroup label="Select Starting Station">
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden style="text-align:center">From</option>
            <option name="table1" value="1">1</option>
            <option name="table2" value="2">2</option>
        </optgroup>
        </select>
        
      <input type="submit" id="submit-form" />
      </fieldset>
  </form>

  <% if(imgsrc == 0) { %>
    <img src = "/images/default.png" />
  <% } else if(imgsrc == 1) { %>
    <img src = "/images/1.png" />
  <% } else if(imgsrc == 2) { %>
    <img src = "/images/2.png" />
  <% } %>
```

and `users.js`

```
var variabled = 0;

router.get("/index2", function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(variabled);
  res.render("index2", {title: 'some data', imgsrc : variabled});
  variabled = 0;
});

router.post("/details", function(req, res, next) {
  variabled = req.body.selectpicker;
  console.log(variabled);

  res.redirect("/users/index2");
})
```

This code works fine, but the page is refreshed everytime I click on submit. I want the image to change without refreshing the page.

I have guesses about `ajax` and `event.preventDefault()` but I don't know how to implement them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can creat seprate route for posting data to the server.

```
app.post('/test', (req, res) =>{
const testObject = {
    name:'John Doe',
    email:'john@email.com'
};
res.json(testObject);
});
```

At client side you can use [fetch API][1] make a post request.

```
fetch('http://example.com/test', {
method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
},
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => { return console.log(data)})
.catch(err => { return console.log(err)} )
```

You can also use XMLHttpRequest in browser.